# Socket & access to many class with the same name

Tags: c#

i listen to tcp port and when i  received a first from source ip , then i create a new instance of  special class for this new source ip

in the second packet from that source ip i do not need to create a new instance of class

my problem is how can i pass this second packet to that class i created for that source ip in particular although i created many classes for different sources ip

and if this is a wrong way ,what is the best way to do that?

thanks in advance

Comment: Your question makes no sense.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
   {
    class1 x=new class1()
   } how to pass a value to the third instance (for example)

Comment: i edited my question please read it again

Comment: Your question still doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `Dictionary` to store the mapping of IP addresses to processing objects.  The class `Session` in the following code corresponds to your special processing class.  The other classes and properties may need to be changed -- provide some of your code if you need more specifics.

```
private Dictionary<IPAddress,Session> activeSessions =  new Dictionary<IPAddress,Session>();

private void packetReceived(Packet pkt)
{
    Session curSession;
    if (!activeSessions.TryGetValue(pkt.SourceIP, out curSession))
    {
        curSession = new Session();
        activeSessions.Add(pkt.SourceIP, curSession);
    }

    curSession.ProcessPacket(pkt);
}
```

Comment: You could use trygetkey instead of ContainsKey and the indexer to avoid two lookup when all you needs is one

Comment: @Rune FS: good idea, edited (I assume you meant `TryGetValue`)

Answer (score 1):

So you've got something that's listening in on a socket. When data comes in you inspect the source IP. If its a new IP, you instantiate an object to handle it. Going forward you want all subsequent packets from that source IP to go to the already instantiated class, right?

Just give your processing class a property such as `SourceIp`. In your class that is initially receiving the packets create an array/list of all instantiated classes. When a packet comes in, loop through the array and see if there's already an instantiated object.

**UPDATE**

I'm going to expand upon @Justin's code a little but I agree that a `Dictionary` is probably the best type. Let's say that you've got this class that process a packet:

```
class Processor
{
    public void ProcessPacket(Byte[] data)
    {
        //Your processing code here
    }
}
```

You first need to c
In your code that receives the data I'm assuming you have both the data itself as well as the source IP. When data is received you look up the IP in the Dictionary and either create a new processor or re-use an existing one:

```
    //Holds our processor classes, each identified by IP
    private Dictionary<IPAddress, Processor> Processors = new Dictionary<IPAddress,Processor>();

    private void dataReceived(Byte[] data, IPAddress ip)
    {
        //If we don't already have the IP Address in our dictionary
        if(!Processors.ContainsKey(ip)){
            //Create a new processor object and add it to the dictionary
            Processors.Add(ip, new Processor());
        }
        //At this point we've either just added a processor for this IP
        //or there was one already in the dictionary so grab it based
        //on the IP
        Processor p = Processors[ip];
        //Tell it to process our data
        p.ProcessPacket(data);
    }
```

Comment: many many thanks  Chris Haas  ,i'm very happy to understanding my question , yes this is my question ,but how i can call that class although all different  class has the same name

i know that property can help but in the end i will use the name of class to call it